# Why this node.js code is not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

the Node js code written below should give some error and stop but it compile properly and give unexpected product.

**the code below doest not throwing error instead it runs and give output of two line like below:-**

santu

connnection estabished

**and then it stops**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mynewdb').
then(()=>{console.log("connnection estabished")})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});


//create a schema
const createschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String
    },
    email:{
        type : String,

        validate(value){
            console.log(value);
            if(validator.isEmail(value)===false){
                throw new Error('invalid Email');
            }
        }
    }
})
//creating a collection/model
const mycollection1 = new mongoose.model("mycollection1",createschema);


const insertdata = async()=>{
    try{
        const doc1 = new mycollection1({
            name : "santu1",
            email : "santu"
        })
        const mydata = await doc1.save();
        console.log(mydata);
    }
    catch{(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    }}
}
insertdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `validate()` function for the `email` field in the schema definition needs to return a boolean, but you're throwing an error instead. Try this:

```js
validate(value){
    return validator.isEmail(value)
}
```